# Rmarkdown, pandoc/PDFlatex, and underscores in a temporary directory name - a problem

Tags: r, configuration, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I have an R markdown document that has a chunk that generates a plot using ggplot2 and a custom function, progress.plot.  The chunk looks like this

````
```{r charts, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Your progress curve"}

progress.plot(student)

```
````

This document generates a PDF using a LaTeX engine.  I think it uses PDFlatex via pandoc.  This is causing a problem.

It seems like Rmarkdown uses a temporary folder to store the diagram I generate with ggplot2.  The name of that folder has underscores.  This means the path to the graphic file, a string that's used in the .tex source file, has an underscore.  And the latex compiler doesn't like that.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.142 ...de2020-05-06_files/figure-latex/charts-1}
                                                   \caption[Your progress cu...
```

I am getting a "Missing $ inserted" error before the latex compiler craps out.  No PDF is generated and the directory with the figure is deleted. (I have experience with LaTeX, so I'm familiar with this type of troubleshooting.)

Is there a way to take the underscore out of the temporary directory's name?  Or is there any other workaround that will allow me to generate figures to include in my R markdown document?

Thanks for whatever advice people can share.

Comment: Is this on Windows? did you try updating pandoc/rstudio?

Comment: It's on macOS.  Installs are relatively recent, but will update to see if updates have a positive effect.